# Unable to Run my Class

Tags: java, class, methods, awt, frame

I'm very new to the Java playing field. I was doing this tutorial exercise, and I'm unable to figure out how to run the class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Party {
    public void buildInvite(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Frame f = new Frame();
        Label l = new Label("Party at Tim's");
        Button b = new Button("You bet");
        Button c = new Button("Shoot me");
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.add(l);
    }
}
```

It compiles without any errors. I just run `java Party` but nothing happens. I'm assuming it is supposed to pop up with a window that has text that says "Party at Tim's" and two buttons with "You bet" and "Shoot me." Unless I misinterpreted what I wrote. Will someone inform me with what I'm missing. Any help will be appreciated (Please make it nooby so I can understand), Thank you.

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 3):

You never add any components to the top level window, the Frame, and you never display the Frame by calling `setVisible(true)` or `show()` on it, and so while your code will run, nothing will show up.

On a side note, I strongly recommend that you avoid this current tutorial since it's teaching you use of AWT GUI coding, a library that's already 3-4 generations out of date, and has been out of date for the past 10+ years.

Comment: Any suggestions what I should use? I just saw the book around, and I was like, "Why not try it?"

Comment: @Bananastreet: Either the Java Swing GUI library or the newer JavaFX library or Android.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels for my personal knowledge, shouldn't he declare `Frame` (`Jframe` on swing) as global variables and initialize them on the constructor? Or is it the same?